# Node MongoDB Batch Find?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a function where I pass it an array of IDs.  What I want to do is essentially check to see if the any of the IDs.

Unfortunately I can't do the below because `.find()` has to be used in conjunction with another operation.

Is there a way I can batch find? Each array will contain 100 IDs, and there will be quite a lot of these queries so I'd rather not do them 1 by 1..

```
try {
    const bulk = db.collection('designs').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    ids.forEach(a => {
        bulk.find({"items.meta.id": a})
    });
    const results = await bulk.execute();
    console.log(results)
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

For Clarity:

Im using Mongo as an index for my Firebase data to allow searching capabilities. 
Each design document contains an array called Items whereby an "item" is an object  containing key item data such as ID, name, platform and an object called `meta`.  The meta object contains different information depending on the platform.

What I need to do is send over 100 id's at a time, and then query my designs collection to see if there is object within the items array that contains the id.

If that ID exists in the `items.meta.id` field, then I simply need to push that ID into a new array, and once all 100 ids have been queried, send the array of id's that exist back as the response

EDIT:

I now have the following query that works as intended, however when doing this in Node, it returns the whole document still

https://mongoplayground.net/p/EM9VTs7YYIj

And my code

```
    const results = await collection.aggregate({
        $unwind:  '$items'
    }, {
        $match: {
            'items.meta.id': {
                $in: ids
            },
            'uid': uid
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            '_id': '$items.meta.id'
        }
    }).toArray()

    console.log(results)
```

Returns:

```
[ { _id: 5d9378a333247165d8ea6f22,
    id: 'OczQL9Blwx79ZXtJcgrV',
    name: 'Brewdolf',
    nameci: 'brewdolf',
    uid: '1uD82gAXORYsyimX5Dw23DDAimx1',
    selected_preview_image:
     'designs/1uD82gAXORYsyimX5Dw23DDAimx1/OczQL9Blwx79ZXtJcgrV/images/preview_BrewDolf.png',
    items:
     { active: true,
       id: 'Nz36jpTaJCjp3nsAqsXA',
       platform: 'a',
       price: '1645',
       title:
        'Brewdolph Funny Drinking Reindeer Christmas Craft Beer T-Shirt',
       meta: [Object] },
    tags: null } ]
```

Comment: can you share your schema and sample input array?

Comment: There is no batch find. Batch operation is geared toward write operations. Before talking about solutions, it's best to state what is your use case, and what is the goal you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @kevinadi I've updated the question with what I am trying to achieve. Hopefully this clears things up

Comment: @K20GH As u've already said there is no `bulk.find` query in isolation. As an option why not create a list `array` of `ids` to match and do an aggregation with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/)

Comment: The IDs I want to query are already in an array.  I didn't think `$in` would query against objects within objects within an array?

Comment: @ambianBeing I  should also mention that doing a `$group` on `$items.meta.id` still returns all the ids in the document, when i need the ones that match

Comment: @ambianBeing My items fields is an array of objects, all with an id in the `meta.id` field.  As an example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/pWlj4wVNDtK  You can see its returning all ids, when I only want the one it queries

Comment: @K20GH Okay! I may've gotten the requirement a little off. Tweaked the query a bit [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L7G8BU2WUWQ). See if that works for you and with results you can map the resultant objects list to an `array` of matched ids in JS.

Comment: @ambianBeing Nearly! I've tweaked it again: https://mongoplayground.net/p/EM9VTs7YYIj  Weirdly though, its not working in Node as it still outputs the whole document.  Will update my question so you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage by that **`_id` expression** which is used to group in the query should do it.

**An optimization:** to have that `$match` on `uid` before the the unwinding of **`array` of items**. (primarily to reduce documents for the next stage in the pipeline).

```
const results = await db
  .collection("target_collection")
  .aggregate(
    {
      $match: {
        uid: uid
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$items"
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "items.meta.id": {
          $in: ids //array
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$items.meta.id"
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        "_id": 1
      }
    }
  )
  .toArray();
```

**Results (demo):**

```
[{"_id":"gop"},{"_id":"foo"}]
```